# JQuery click method bug or programming error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been learning JQuery and encountered an error.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#gbutton").click(function( tries = $("#guesses").val(),
                                  guess = $("#guess").val(),
                                  rnumber = $("#rnumber").val() || (Math.floor(Math.random()*500)+1)){
        if (tries < 1) return;

        var result;
        if (guess == rnumber) result = "You win!";
        else if (guess > rnumber) result = "Too high!";
        else if (guess < rnumber) result = "Too low!";

        $("#guesses").val(tries-1);
        $("#rnumber").val(rnumber);
        $("#result").val(result);
        return;
    });
});
```

What happens is `tries` returns an object instead of a number. I've been messing around for a while now, and eventually "fixed" it. Thing is, my fix doesn't make any sense. It just works. Still, I'm confused as to why it worked.

To fixed it, I ended up just adding another argument to my code like so:

```
.click(function(x,
                tries = $("#guesses").val(),
                guess = $("#guess").val(),
                rnumber = $("#rnumber").val() || (Math.floor(Math.random()*500)+1))
```

And it just works. At this point I'm just confuzzled. What was I doing wrong? Was I doing anything wrong? Why does this work?

Comment: I'm confused by your 'it returns an object' statement. `val()` should be returning a string, however you should note that your syntax of defining variables in the parameters of the function is incorrect. A more complete sample of your logic with the relevant HTML may help here.

Comment: Sorry. What happens is that `$("#guesses").val(tries-1);` changes the original value to NaN. Using console.log to check the initial value of tries, it says that tries is an Object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery event handler for `click` event is expected to have very specific signature - https://api.jquery.com/click/ . jQuery is not going to call your anonymous function passing it three parameters. The parameter will be only one, and it will `event` object.

```
$("#gbutton").click(function(event) {
  var tries1 = $("#guesses").val(),
      guess1 = $("#guess").val(),
      rnumber1 = $("#rnumber").val() || (Math.floor(Math.random()*500)+1);

  check(tries1, guess1, rnumber1);      

  function check(tries, guess, rnumber) {
    if (tries < 1) 
      return;

    var result;
    if (guess == rnumber) 
      result = "You win!";
    else if (guess > rnumber) 
      result = "Too high!";
    else if (guess < rnumber) 
      result = "Too low!";

    $("#guesses").val(tries-1);
    $("#rnumber").val(rnumber);
    $("#result").val(result);
  }
});
```

Comment: Okay then. I'm a little confused about the event object and it's purpose, but I understand otherwise. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are including the variables in the wrong place. The vars(tries, guess, and rnumber) should not be passed in as params. See below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#gbutton").click(function() {

    tries = $("#guesses").html(),
    guess = $("#guess").val(),
    rnumber = $("#rnumber").val() || (Math.floor(Math.random()*500)+1);
    if (tries < 1) return;

    var result;
    if (guess == rnumber) result = "You win!";
    else if (guess > rnumber) result = "Too high!";
    else if (guess < rnumber) result = "Too low!";

    $("#guesses").val(tries-1);
    $("#rnumber").val(rnumber);
    $("#result").val(result);
    return;
  });
});
```

in your code, 'tries' is being overwritten by the event. That is why adding 'x' makes it work. Cause now 'x' is being overwritten, and you dont need 'x'.

Comment: tries, guess and rnumber are not variables their parameters. I'd always understood that a function like `function example(x = 10){...}` passes 10 as the default argument if no other argument is specified.

Comment: you can set defaults like that, but they will be overwritten if a value is passed in. that is what is happening to tries. it is being overwritten by the event handler being passing in.  https://api.jquery.com/click/